# Deleting file/folder from Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce

I'm running an EMR Activity inside a Data Pipeline analyzing log files and I get the following error when my **Pipeline fails**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://10.208.42.127:9000/home/hadoop/temp-output-s3copy already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:905)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1316)
    at com.valtira.datapipeline.stream.CloudFrontStreamLogProcessors.main(CloudFrontStreamLogProcessors.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
```

How can I delete that folder from Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted AWS support and it seemed that the problem was that the log files I was analyzing were very big and that created an issue with memory. I added to my pipeline definition "masterInstanceType" : "m1.xlarge" in the EMRCluster section and it worked.

Comment: This is the answer to your question but not the answer to the question's title.

Answer (score 53):

When you say delete from Hadoop, you really mean delete from HDFS.

To delete something from HDFS do one of the two

From the command line:

- deprecated way:

`hadoop dfs -rmr hdfs://path/to/file`

- new way (with hadoop 2.4.1) :

`hdfs dfs -rm -r hdfs://path/to/file`

Or from java:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
fs.delete(new Path("path/to/file"), true); // delete file, true for recursive
```

Comment: path/to/file is "10.208.42.127:9000/home/hadoop/temp-output-s3copy"? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. My question is should I use "10.208.42.127:9000/home/hadoop/temp-output-s3copy" as path/to/file?

Comment: usually you just specify hdfs://home/hadoop/temp-output-s3copy, since files on hdfs are often replicated to several nodes. Are you doing this on a single node?

Comment: Well if this folder is on HDFS then it should work. Though the path you gave makes me think its not on HDFS at all and instead is just a local folder.  Are you doing this through command line or java?

Comment: Im creating the pipeline through the command line, but my loganalyzer is done in Java

Comment: So use the command line version `hadoop dfs -rmr hdfs://home/hadoop/temp-output-s3copy`. If that doesn't work, it's because it's not on the hdfs file system.  If thats the case.. you can use `hadoop dfs -rmr file://home/hadoop/temp-output-s3copy`, or just the unix `rm -r`

Comment: From Java, did you mean FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(fs.getConf());? I added the fs.getConf()

Comment: It really depends on the hadoop api version.  Just use whatever you need to get the current configuraiton, if thats `fs.getConfg` then use that.

Comment: It's not a local folder, so I'm pretty sure it is in Hadoop. I'll try this and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: So it worked the first time I run the EMRActivity. I run again using the same java class, same Pipeline configuration, but different dates and it doesn't work. I get the exact same error. The only difference that I see is in the numbers at hdfs://10.208.42.127:9000/home/hadoop/temp-output-s3copy already exists. Every new time I run the Pipeline, I get a different number. I do not know what that means. I was suggested to delete the output from S3, but it still failed.

Comment: I contacted AWS support and it seemed that the problem was that the log files I was analyzing were very big and that created an issue with memory. I added to my pipeline definition "masterInstanceType" : "m1.xlarge" in the EMRCluster section and it worked. Thanks

Comment: how can we achieve same with python ?

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

Answer (score 15):

To delete a file from hdfs you can use below given command :

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash /path_to_file/file_name
```

To delete a folder from hdfs you can use below given command :

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash /folder_name
```

You need to use -skipTrash option otherwise error will be prompted.

Answer (score 7):

With Scala:

```
val fs:FileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(filePath), sc.hadoopConfiguration);
fs.delete(new Path(filePath), true) // true for recursive
```

sc is the SparkContext

Comment: Just what I was looking for: includes recursive flag and from sparkContext.

Answer (score 2):

To delete a file from hdfs use the command: 
`hadoop fs -rm -r /FolderName`

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
 hadoop fs -rm -r /folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I use hadoop 2.6.0, the commande line 'hadoop fs -rm -r fileName.hib' works fine for deleting any hib file on my hdfs file sys